# How to run node.js in my web site server not my pc local server

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

Last 2 days I spent more time and read 50+ articles and video to understand node.js and after installation now I can see the result in browser by `http//:localhost:3000/` But I have confused in many case that I describe below.

I do all of my work in my share hosting server where I my keep my web site: `www.myweb.com`

In every article about node.js, they are teaching how to get a result by below code in a browser by `http//:localhost:3000/` in local pc server.

test.js

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(3000);
console.log('Server running at http://localhost:3000/');
```

But My Question:

1. If I use http//:www.myweb.com/test.js` in my browser, What will be the above code?
2. In case of local pc we write on npm `node test.js`, But In case of hosting server when any clint open the page like `http//:www.myweb.com/test.js` How to work it?
3. In case of php we used include ("head.php") to got something from that page But In this case How to make a call on node.js.

Comment: Go to `http://www.myweb.com:3000`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, what you need to do is understand how http web servers works.

Usually, on your remote machine (your server), you have an instance of a web server (ex : apache) running, which is listening to port 80 (standard port for http requests). It will handle every request made on that port, and manage routing to use the correct php/html file.

Then, it will run the php code **server-side**, to render an html file and serve it to the server. So the client will not see the php code at all.

Let's talk about Node.js. Node is an application that runs javascript code server-side, and **can** run an http server with using some modules. But the javascript code will never be shown to your client, he will only get the http response you send him (typically, the html page).

So now, with node.js, you need to do the same as the apache server did, by creating the http server. First, what you have to know is that not that many website host are offering node.js, or even console access. They usually serve the php/html files you put in the configured folder, and that's basically it. What you need is either a virtual machine, or a server on which you can install node.js and run it, or use a node.js hosting service, like heroku or nodejitsu to host your node.js http server.

So, to create the node.js http server, you need to create an http server (as you did in your code), and make it listen to port 80. Now, every http request send to your server will be handled by your node.js instance. Then, you can do anything you want with that request.

I hope I haven't been to messy.

Comment: If share hosting server provider cannot support node.js. what will be the alternative way that work like as same in share hosting please?

Comment: Well, you have several different possibilities : 
 use php, which is supported by any server provider
| use a node.js server provider
| reroute the request from your existing http server to a node.js server

But to be clear, if you want to use node.js, you need a node.js instance running somewhere.

Comment: Another option would be to load static web pages from your apache server, and dynamically load resources from a Node.js server running elsewhere using ajax or web sockets requests.

Comment: Have any free web server to your knowledge that support node.js. I am felling so sad because I can't go ahead with node.js after long try. Thank you so much.

Comment: I haven't used free node.js hosting, but I think red hat offers some free hosting on openshift. You may check this out : https://www.openshift.com/products/pricing

Answer (score 0):

You need to install NodeJS on the server. If this is shared hosting where you cannot install additional software then you will be unable to use NodeJS. In that case contact support of your web hosting company and inquire about NodeJS support.

On the other hand, if you do have root user or super user rights on a system, you can install NodeJS. For example for on CentOS/RHEL systems you can install using yum with the following commands.

```
sudo yum install epel-release
sudo yum install npm
```

For some of the other distributions of Linux: http://ask.xmodulo.com/install-node-js-linux.html

To access Node applications from your PC to the server, you also need to open a port in the server firewall that your Node aplication uses.